# Is it possible to autocomplete column names in a SSMS query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, ssms-2012

I'm new to SQL Server and today I began writing an SQL query. While writing SQL queries in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) for insert statements, I noticed that only table names were getting auto completed, but there is no option to auto complete the column name. Is there any way to autocomplete column names in a query?

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
/* Here table name is auto completed. When i type a,a related tables were generated, but for columns there is no autocomplete. */
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Comment: This totally depends on the SQL client you are using. SQL Server itself never does "auto completion" (because SQL Server is a non-gui application).

Comment: Assuming you are using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), which most use people use when working with SQL Server, there is a weaker built in Intellisense that will fill in certain parts of SQL queries for you.  If you want something stronger, you can check out third party addins.  The most popular are probably SQL Prompt by Red Gate and SQL Complete by dbForge.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg third party addin helped me to resolve the issue,kindly quote ur comment as answer i will accept over it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), which most use people use when working with SQL Server, there is a weaker built in Intellisense that will fill in certain parts of SQL queries for you. If you want something stronger, you can check out third party addins. The most popular are probably [SQL Prompt by Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) and [SQL Complete by dbForge](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/).